# Yoast SEO confliction with category_description wp

Tags: wordpress, function, categories

I'm a little lost, the pages in question that call function b have no issue showing the `category_description` correctly and in the correct place. function a however shows the `category_description` both at the top of the header and in the correct place. When I turn off Yoast SEO the problem goes away. How is it that one function isnt getting effected by Yoast SEO but the second function is.

`functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'category_description', 'show_category_description', 10, 2 );
function show_category_description ( $description, $category ) 
{
    if( is_category( array(2,3) ) )  {
        $description = functionb($content . $output);
    } elseif ( is_category( array(7) ) )  {
        $description = functiona($output2);
    } else {
        $description = functionb($content . $output);
    }
    return $description;
}



function functiona($output2) {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            ?>           
            <div class="accordion-container" id="UserSubmit">
            <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle">Submit your own Weekly Challenge here!<span class="toggle-icon"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>
        <div class="accordion-content"><?
        // the user is logged in, so display the submission form
        if (function_exists('user_submitted_posts')) user_submitted_posts();
        ?></div></div>
        <? } else { 
        // Show nothing
        ?><p>Sorry, but you must be logged in to submit a weekly challenge<p><? }
        return $output2;
}
```

Thank you for any help you can give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5min more poking around I remembered I can override the in-page Yoast SEO category description.

The quick fix seems to be putting a `&nbsp;` in.

If anyone still knows of a better way please feel free to let me know